# Python while Loop common mistake

Tags: python

I am new in this forum and I want to ask question regarding Python. There's a common while Loop problem in this. It print blank can someone explain it to me why it print blank? Thank you.

```
i=0
sum=0
while sum<10:
 i+=1
sum+=i
print(i, '', sum)
```

Comment: Your `sum` is outside the `while` loop, this is a pretty basic error

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? What do you want the output to be?

Comment: Hi Joe, I have been ask to spot the problem and comment on. And as a newbie I was really struggling to give any tangible explanation

Comment: Are you saying that this question was a homework assignment?

Comment: it is not only this one it's a whole lot but this was the beginning of the  questions. I might post the toughest one pretty soon. So to get the basic idea i decided to post the most basic so i can understand from the basic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a homework answering service.

Comment: I am not a student I am learning on my own but these are some of the questions you might answer when taking couple of trials.

Comment: A good help is to print some values if the programm doesn't run as expected. In your case you could add `print i` after `i+=1` line and see that `i` is counting forever. Or not see if you would miss the correct indentation again :) That would give you some information too. Or you could change `print(i, '', sum)` to `print(i, ' text ', sum)` and see that "text" is never printed.

Comment: I did print i and it's still the same. I also did add text inside the quotes and its still not visible

Comment: @paapame in python places are also important

Comment: I put the sum inside the loop and it worked. Thank you for your help -_-

Answer (score 0):

```
i,sum= 0,0
while sum<10:
   i=i+1
   sum +=i
   print(str(i)+" "+str(sum)) #we need to convert to string as space is string and others are int
```

output

```
1 1
2 3
3 6
4 10
```